# How to remove input type hidden from html?

Tags: django, html

I am working with Django forms and html. The text area will create when I put input into that output will come but text box will go off. After getting output also text area should be there

forms.py:

```
   from django import forms
     class ReportForm(forms.Form):
         text = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 5, 'cols': 100}))
```

html:

```
   {% extends 'base.html' %}
   {% block content %}
   <h1>StopWordsRemoval</h1>
     <div>
        <form method = "post" >
            {% csrf_token %}
              {{ form.as_p }} 

       <button type="submit">stopwordsremoval</button>
</div>



<div >
 <ul>

        <li>{{ naturallanguageprocessing }}</li>

              </ul>
            <a href="{% url 'stopwordsremoval' %}" </a>
     <style>
       div {
width: 1000px;
border: 5px solid green;
padding: 10px;
margin: 10px;
   }
  </style>
   </div>
          </div>

          {% endblock %}
```

In between form `as_p` and button line input type hidden is created. If we can replace input type text then problem will solve.